# How to decode special characters in an NSURL in Swift?

Tags: swift, decode, nsurl, nsurlsession

I have a string: `<api address>/<parameters>?fmt=json` 
When I create an NSURL object from the string, the URL is: `<api address>/<parameters>%3Ffmt=json`

When I send the request with this URL (using an NSURLSession), however, it gets denied access, as the API wants the `?` and doesn't accept `%3F`. How do I decode the URL to have the `?` return so the API will accept the request?

**UPDATE**

NSURL construction

`let urlRequestString = "<api url>?fmt=json&api_key=" + <key>
let apiRequestURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: urlRequestString)`

Comment: Please show how you make the `NSURL` object

Comment: @ZoffDino
let urlRequestString = "<api url>?fmt=json&api_key=" + <key>
let apiRequestURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: urlRequestString)

Comment: Are you trying to load a file, or communicate with a web server?

Comment: Communicate with a web server. The server will be returning a JSON block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the wrong initializer, which is causing bogus results. `NSURL(fileURLWithPath: urlRequestString)` is intended for creating `file://` URLs. It translates your URL into a format suitable for the filesystem. It's designed for file use only, so you shouldn't use it here.

If you change the initializer to be `NSURL(string: urlRequestString)` then your URL should be OK.